# Haml %noscript tag generating wrong html result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

here is my ruby on rails / haml code

```
%noscript
  %iframe{ :src => "https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=#{key}", :style => "display:none;visibility:hidden",:height => "0", :width => "0"}
```

and this is the expected html out.

```
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

but it generates

```
<noscript>
"
<iframe height='0' src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX' style='display:none;visibility:hidden' width='0'></iframe>
"
</noscript>
```

as you can see, iframe is wrapped by "" quotes. Why this is happening?
I also tried using src: "..." instead of using :src => "..." but id did`nt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you viewing the generated HTML? It looks like you are using the browsers inspector which is adding the quotes when displaying. They do not appear in the actual HTML. If you use “View Source” rather than the element inspector you should see what you expect.

Comment: Yeah i was doing just like that... Thank for the information